# bad symbolic reference on SQLContext.class in Eclipse Luna scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, eclipse-luna

I have setup eclipse for scala IDE on a Linux box. I get the following error on build

bad symbolic reference. A signature in SQLContext.class refers to term types in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available.

I understand from other similar questions in stackoverflow that I'm missing a dependency. However I am not sure what I am missing.
I have the following jars in the build path

```
spark-core_2.10-1.5.2.jar
spark-sql_2.10-1.5.2.jar
spark-graphx_2.10-1.5.2.jar
spark-hive_2.10-1.5.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

[image: Project dependencies in Eclipse Scala IDE]

Any idea?

Comment: I'd suggest you use some thing to manage the dependencies for you, like SBT or maven.

Comment: Unfortunately the setup is in a secure cluster that has no internet access. I do use Maven in my local setup.

Answer (score 0):

Added scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar to the project dependency to solve this. Thanks!